# Help with SpringLayout?

Tags: java, user-interface, layout-manager

I have a very odd problem when I use Java's SpringLayout manager.  I'm triyng to get a tool bar to appear in my program.  It was working at an earlier point in my program and now it does not work.  Basically, if I remove the layout parameter from my instantiation of a JPanel the elements that I have added in the JPanel show up, albeit without my customizations.  If I have that parameter in the instantiation, the toolbar does not appear at all.  I have no idea what I jacked up or am doing wrong.  The JPanel is going into a central JFrame, which I've changed around from a BorderLayout to another SpringLayout to nothing and it does not seem to affect this problem.

```
public class purchaserApp
{
static JFrame mainWindow;                                   //Main window
static JFrame addView = new JFrame ("Add An Item...");      //Add item window
static JFrame aboutView = new JFrame ("About Purchaser");   //About window
static JFrame helpView = new JFrame ("Purchaser Help");     //Help window
static JPanel toolBar, contentArea, previewPane;            //Panels for GUI
static JRootPane root;
static JToolBar toolBar2;
//SpringLayout mainLayout;
JTable table;

public purchaserApp()
{
    makemainWindow();
    makeMenu();
    makeToolbar();
     // makeMainContentView();
    mainWindow.setVisible(true);

}
public void makeToolbar()
{
    SpringLayout tbLayout = new SpringLayout();
    toolBar = new JPanel(tbLayout);     //this is the offending line of code, if I remove "tbLayout" the buttons show up in the GUI but obviously without the customizations I made below...
    JButton toolBarButtons[];
    String buttonNames[] = {"Add", "Edit", "Delete"};
    //Instantiate buttons for toolbar
    toolBarButtons = new JButton[3];
    //Resize
    Dimension d = new Dimension (40,55);

    //Add/modify/whatever
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        toolBarButtons[i] = new JButton(buttonNames[i]);
        toolBarButtons[i].setPreferredSize(d);
        tbLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, toolBarButtons[i], 5, SpringLayout.NORTH, toolBar);
    }

    //Adjust constraints
    tbLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, toolBarButtons[0], 5, SpringLayout.WEST, toolBar);
    tbLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, toolBarButtons[1], 5, SpringLayout.EAST, toolBarButtons[0]);
    tbLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, toolBarButtons[2], -5, SpringLayout.EAST, toolBar);       //due to x-axis, we must go negative to get inside the frame
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        toolBar.add(toolBarButtons[i]);

    mainWindow.add(toolBar,BorderLayout.NORTH);   //Lies! Does not add

}
```

I've included here the class and the offending method.  Any help would be most greatly appreciated as I'm sure I am not the first one to have this problem. I also apologize if this is a relatively simple fix and I did not see it. I'm still sorta new to Java GUIs (and Java in general) so please excuse me.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to create a toolbar using a panel? Whats wrong with JToolBar which uses its own custom layout?

Even if you did create a custom toolbar panel I wouldn't use a SpringLayout, its too complicated. Just use a FlowLayout or a horizontal BoxLayout.

Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for working examples of each layout manager.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did consider using the JToolBar.  However, the way the requirements are, I need a button on either side of the pane (extreme left and extreme right in other words) and Spring seemed to fit that role most.  Also, I tried using GridBagLayout and that frustrated me beyond belief because it also did not function properly.   Is it still possible in JToolbar to have buttons on either side of the pane?

Comment: Either `FlowLayout` or a horizontal `BoxLayout` can do this.

Comment: @Stefan, I believe the JToolBar layout extends BoxLayout so you can just add some "glue" between your buttons to get them on the left and right. Check out the BoxLayout tutorial if you don't know what glue is.

Comment: Thanks again for the response. camickr, I have just tried a JToolBar. However, even when I use setPreferredSize(), my JButtons get resized to very small rectangles when adding them to the JToolBar.  I am not sure why this occurs.  I also had this issue before, which is why I switched to a JPane over a JToolbar.

Comment: Update: This appears to be a OS X "feature".  I just downloaded a JToolBar demo from Oracle's site and the button on OS X shows up as small as mine, even though the picture on the demo page suggests that it is sized normally.

Comment: @Stefan, You should never use setPreferredSize() to size a button. All Swing components have a preferred size and there is generally no need to override this, especially for a button.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445776), the order of constraint specification may be important, particularly if the resulting layout is [*over-constrained*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SpringLayout.Constraints.html). Depending on the version, you may have to specify the `EAST/SOUTH` constraints before the `WEST/NORTH` constraints, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445776).